# How to show error on button click in React native?

Tags: validation, react-native, textfield

I am using 'react-native-material-textfield' and it working well, but I need to show error for empty field when clicking on submit button. I have searched lot-of but didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Put the error message in your state and fill it with a message after clicking on the submit button, if your validation process fails.

```
render(){
  return (
    <View>
      <TextField
        {...props}
        error={this.state.error}
        errorColor={'red'}
        onFocus={() => this.setState({error: ''})}
      />
      <Button {...props} />
    </View>)}
```

Check the [example](https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-textfield/blob/master/example/app.js) on the developers github repository.

Answer (score 0):

According to the module documentation and examples, whenever your this.state.errors for each field is not empty, its error is shown. So your form should look like this:

```
class Form extends Component {

  // ... Some required methods

  onSubmit() {
    let errors = {};
    ['firstname'] // This array should be filled with your fields names.
      .forEach((name) => {
        let value = this[name].value();
        if (!value) {
          errors[name] = 'Should not be empty'; // The error message when field is empty
        }
      });
    this.setState({ errors });
  }

  render() {
    let { errors = {}, data } = this.state;
    return (
      <View>
        <TextField
          value={data.firstname}
          onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
          error={errors.firstname}
        />
      <Text onPress={this.onSubmit}>Submit</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using the same from "https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-textfield" but it is not working.